# Generating multiples of a report without closing one of them

Tags: vba, ms-access

Is it possible to do this in MS Access? Right now if I want to generate the same report (with different info) I have to close the one I already have open. If I click "open report" it will just take me to the one I already generated and not actually make a new one. Can I make it so it will open the report in a new tab while also keeping the previous one open?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is.

You need a module level Collection object to hold each report's reference. In addition, you need to set the report's `Has Module` property to **Yes** in order to be visible in VBE. It is located in the tab *Other*.

In the Form which opens the report:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private mInstances As Collection

'Load
Private Sub Form_Load()
   Set mInstances = New Collection
End Sub

'Create report instance
Private Sub YourButtonName_Click()

    Dim rpt As Report_ReportName
    Set rpt = New Report_ReportName

    With rpt
        .Visible = True
        .Caption = rpt.Hwnd & ", opened " & Now()
    End With

    mInstances.Add rpt

    Set rpt = Nothing
End Sub

'Close
Private Sub Form_Close()
    Set mInstances = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting, but how would you go about opening them with different data? i.e. simulating different `WhereCondition` or `OpenArgs`?

Comment: @Andre I don't know how the report is being generated. Usually it's linked to a query where different values are being passed.So each report instance will display the values passed to the query upon opening the report. Opening a new instance will not requery any opended report instances.